# Need to create a trigger in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

i have a master pipeline inside that i have 18 pipelines for 18 tables they are running in parallel
i need to create a trigger in such a way that
for suppose 1 pipeline in that 18 pipelines run at 9 to 9:12
it should run every 15 min like 9:12+00:15===9:27 it has to run
is there any way to achieve this scenario.

Comment: please help on this

Comment: can you add image of your master pipeline?

Comment: it has so many execute pipelines in it in that we are defining a switch statement calling the 18 individual pipelines.

Comment: as you said you are calling child pipeline using execute pipeline activity currently we can't trigger specific activity in pipeline. As you said you have 18 pipelines for 18 tables and want to trigger 1 from them so you can impose schedule trigger on it with recurrence 15 mins.

Comment: that pipeline will get triggered every 15 mins after irrespective of main pipeline

Comment: what happen if the pipeline is run for more than 15 min ?

Comment: Assuming each pipeline duration is < 15mins, since each pipeline can run for different durations(0-15mins), you need to store the start and stop time in a storage (like SQL). Then your master pipeline would need to trigger every 1 min and check the SQL data first and only then trigger the child pipeline if 15mins has past since last completion. This kind of setup is pretty complicated. It would help if you gave the reasoning behind this kind of requirement as compared to triggering the master pipeline every 15mins.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this using a Wait-Block:

[image]

Important to note here, that you need to connect the blocks using the "onCompletion" and not "onSuccess":

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-pipeline-failure-error-handling